# Using Away3D, how do I manipulate the camera, so that I see all scene objects all the time?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, camera

The problem that I'm having is that objects in my scene move around all the time. I have a hover camera, which also changes angles, but I need it to sort of zoom in and out automatically, based on the dimensions of the scene, so that the whole scene is always in view. Sure, when it hovers, it moves back and forth, but it is obviously not enough, because a lot of objects remain unseen.

Comment: This helped me a lot: http://www.allforthecode.co.uk/aftc/forum/user/modules/forum/article.php?index=4&subindex=2&aid=101

Answer (score 0):

You would need to start by checking the x,y,z of each object on the scene.  Then you find those with the highest and lowest values.  For example, extremely far left would have the lowest X value.  Then you need to modify your camera's zoom or the camera's position accordingly.